# Scheduled task says it works but it doesn't

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have a windows server, and I' trying to use scheduled tasks.  When I create the job and try to run it through the interface, it says it works, but when I look at the DB it shows me that nothing happend.  This is what I placed in the Path to executable file

```
"D:\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.exe" -f "D:\inetpub\vhosts\fab-offers.com\httpdocs\cms-sites\vipstore\users\index.php"
```

Comment: what's the content of your php?

Comment: regular php script...  simply connection to Mysql and updating some fields...

Comment: is it works through win+r cmd ?

Comment: sorry, just read it, and marked all the helpers, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for:

1. Is the script working if you run it manualy?
2. Does php error logs contain anything related to the script?
3. Does the script contain paths like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` that it won't have when run not from browser?

Comment: no it has nothing like that.  simple mysql connection and update table.  threw the browser it works great

Comment: Do a simple `file_put_contents("test.log", "1");` at the start of the script. If it won't shoot and php error logs are empty - then script doesnt start and you need to work on the scheduler. Simple to debug.